# How to use CSS sticky

Tags: html, css, position, sticky

I've created simple table that is supposed to have sticky header(TR) at the top. But this does not work. How can I fix this code?

Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML><HEAD></HEAD><BODY>
<P>HELLO<P>

<TABLE BORDER=1 STYLE="border: 3px solid #4285F4;background-color:#EEEEEE;width:1600px;">
<thead STYLE="position: sticky; top:0;">
<TR    style="border:0px solid #888888;">
<TH STYLE="height:200px;width:800px;">hello 5</TH><TH STYLE="width:800px;">hello 5</TH>
</TR>
</thead>

<TR style="">
<TD STYLE="height:200px;">hello 5</TD><TD>hello 5</TD></TR>
</TABLE>

HELLO TEXT 1

<TABLE BORDER=1 STYLE="position: sticky; top: 0;border-collapse: collapse;border: 3px solid #4285F4;background-color:#EEEEEE;">
<TR    style="border:0px solid #888888;">
<TD STYLE="height:200px;">hello 5</TD><TD>hello 5</TD>
</TR>
<TR style="">
<TD STYLE="height:200px;">hello 5</TD><TD>hello 5</TD></TR>
</TABLE>

<DIV STYLE="width:1600px;">
HELLO TEXT 3...  HELLO TEXT 3...  HELLO TEXT 3...  HELLO TEXT 3...  HELLO TEXT 3...  HELLO TEXT 3...   
</DIV>

</BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: apply position:sticky on tr not table

Comment: Some notes...don't capitalize your HTML, don't use inline CSS, and don't use tables for layout

Comment: Thanks for helping. I updated code - still no luck :-(

Comment: Also I updated code in this question so you are now looking on updated code

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Try to keep css and html in separate files so your code will be easier to read.

```
tr {
position:sticky;
top:0;
}
```